# Jquery Soap in cross domain requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, soap, cors

I'm working on a rails project and one of my pages needs to create a soap request and send it.

JQuery provided a nice library to make my life easier, the problem is that i try to do a cross domain request.

I installed a gem called rack-cors and configured it to this :

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins '*'
      resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
    end
end
```

so anything should pass properly.

I get the error :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.notmydomain.com/somews.asmx?wsdl. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myawesomedomain.com:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

here is my $.soap code:

```
$.soap({
url: web_service,
method: "wsdl",
data: paymentJSON,
namespaceQualifier: 'env',   // used as namespace prefix for all elements in request
namespaceURL: web_service,    // namespace url added to parent request element
noPrefix: false,
success: function (returnedData) {
    callback.successWithObject(returnedData);
    deferred.resolve(returnedData);
  },
  error: function(err) {
        callback.error(err);
        deferred.reject(err);
    }
});
```

Anyone knows where or how this problem can be solved?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$.soap` i have not found it on jQuery site.

Comment: here is a link to its site : [link](http://plugins.jquery.com/soap/)

Comment: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` its not present there try adding `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` or check in the broswer's network tab and check the request that its available there or not.

Comment: yeah i tried all variations of adding it.
i wouldn't ask it here if it was that simple

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? Looking for a solution to this exact same problem right now.

Comment: @NoahDavis I poster my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try adding headers this way:

#### Rails 4:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
  'Access-Control-Request-Method' => '*'
}
```

Comment: im using rails 3, where should this line get to ?

Answer (score 0):

Back when I asked this I lacked the knowledge in [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) and the problem wasn't on my side. The problem was at the service I tried to communicate with which wasn't in my origin. The other service was using IIS and they didn't configure it to allow CORS.